# using a python class as an object to be started

Tags: python, class

New to OOP and Python, and an old fart, great with procedural coding in c.

Anyway I have created a Python class that works; 
It displays a window with some options for the user. 
I copied a script (a Hello World script) from the web and learned how to modify it to do what I want.

I want to create another class that works very similarly to the first (a clone) for a second level of options when the user selects a particular option in the first.

It should put up another window with the set of choices. 
I've changed the various names I think should be different from the first.

So, my question is how to use the second class as an object and "call" it from the first if the user makes the appropriate selection in the first class.

I have included an import statement for the second class in the first but don't know what should be inserted in the code when the user makes the choice that should invoke the second.

Adding Code Example (suitably edited but not enough, probably):

First file:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import sys
import Example_Edit
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, BOTH
from ttk import Frame, Style

class Main_Loader(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        # Initialize window using the parent's constructor
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,
                          master,
                          width=400,
                          height=300)
        # Set the title
        self.master.title('Main Data Loader')

        # This allows the size specification to take effect
        self.pack_propagate(0)

        # We'll use the flexible pack layout manager
        self.pack()

        # The option selector
        # Use a StringVar to access the selector's value
        self.option_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.option = tk.OptionMenu(self,
                                      self.option_var,
                                      '(Select a Workflow)',
                                      'EDIT Project Data',
                                      'Load SEGY data to IDS',
                                      'Preview a SEGY line',
                                      'Move SEGY file to DBFS'
                                      )
        self.option_var.set('(Select a Workflow)')

#more code to complete the frame



    def do_something(self):

        Edit = Example_Edit.Main_Edit

        if self.option_var.get() == '(Select a Workflow)':
            print('Select a Workflow')
        elif self.option_var.get() == 'EDIT Project Data':
            print('Do--%s' % (self.option_var.get()))
            Edit(self)    :'<===============what goes here===================='
        elif self.option_var.get() == 'Move SEGY file to DBFS':
            print('Do--%s' % (self.option_var.get()))
        elif self.option_var.get() == 'Preview a SEGY line':
            print('Do--%s' % (self.option_var.get()))
        elif self.option_var.get() == 'Load SEGY data to IDS':
            print('Do--%s' % (self.option_var.get()))

    def end_it(self):
        quit() 

    def run(self):
        ''' Run the app '''
        self.mainloop()

app = Main_Loader(tk.Tk())
app.run()
```

Second File:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import sys
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, BOTH
from ttk import Frame, Style

class Main_Edit(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        # Initialize window using the parent's constructor

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,
                          master,
                          width=400,
                          height=300)
        # Set the title
        self.master.title('Main Netadata Editor')



#more code here to complete the frame


    def do_something(self):

#       do stuff

    def end_it(self):
        quit()
```

Ok, here is what I am trying to do.  Be gentle and don't laugh,  I'm a newby.

Comment: Code example would be useful.

Comment: I'm not sure you can 'call' a class, you can call its classmethods and create instances and their methods. Calling a class is a instation method, it creates a new object that is a instance of the class. You should read more about python classes in https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a subclass of the first class.

something like this:

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self,value,text):
        self.value = value
        self.text = text

    def show_values(self):
        print self.value,self.text

class myCloneClass(myClass):
    def show_values(self):
        print "Value:",self.value
        print "Text:",self.text

a = myClass(1,'Hello')
b = myCloneClass(2,'World')
a.show_values()
b.show_values()
```

Output:

```
1 Hello
Value: 2
Text: World
```

> I want to create another class that works very similarly to the first (a clone)

myClass have a method that prints it's values, but not in a proper format,
myCloneClass have the same method, called by the same name, that prints its values in a better way

---

> how to use the second class as an object and "call" it from the first
>   if the user makes the appropriate selection in the first class

Or maybe you are looking for a class object inside another class object

something like this:

```
class myFirstClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = raw_input("What is favorite color? ")
        print "Your favorite color is",self.color
        if self.color == 'blue':
            self.sub_instance = mySecondClass()

class mySecondClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.food = raw_input("What is favorite food? ")
        print "Your favorite food is", self.food

a = myFirstClass()
```

'a' is a instance of the myFirstClass, if the user selected 'blue' as its favorite color it creates a new nameplace called self.sub_instance, which is a instance of the mySecondClass. I don't know why you would want something like this, since you can use the first class to store new values. It's a rather cumbersome way of handling things.

To access the favorite food you need to use eihter:

```
a.sub_instance.food # outside the myFirstClass
self.sub_instance.food # inside the myFirstClass
```

But it will fail if the favorite color isn't 'blue' in the first place, because it would create the new nameplace(self.sub_instance), raising a AttributeError.

Comment: I believe you missed the point.  The OP is trying to import the first class to use it from the second, not to subclass it.

Comment: The OP question is ambiguous, I tried two different approach to what I grasp what he is trying, he mentions cloning(for me this is subclassing) and calling the second class as an object in the first(the second approach).

Comment: Ok, that's a valid point.  I interpreted ‘cloning’ as copying and adapting, so I assumed he'd have two separate files.

Answer (score 0):

Making another answer, to avoid confusion.

This line:

```
Edit = Example_Edit.Main_Edit
```

Should be

```
Edit = Example_Edit.Main_Edit(self)
```

Here you are creating a nameplace called Edit, which is a instance of the Main_Edit class, which is in the Example_Edit file, since Main_Edit takes one argument, a class instance(you called it master), you passing it all together(the 'self').

Next:

```
Edit(self)  '<===============what goes here===================='
```

You can replace it and start using Edit methods[from the Main_Edit class].

Simply doing this:

```
elif self.option_var.get() == 'EDIT Project Data':
    Edit.do_something()
elif self.option_var.get() == 'end':
    Edit.end_it()
```

Edit:

By the way:

In your main_edit class

this line:

```
self.master.title('Main Netadata Editor')
```

should be:

```
self.master.master.title('Main Netadata Editor')
```

because the master class, Main_Loader, uses a master nameplace too.

That's why I said in the other answer that it's cumbersome using class instances inside class instances.

Answer (score -1):

The file name of the other file without the `.py`, then a period, then the name of the class.

So if, for example, your files are called `fileA.py` and `fileB.py` and contain classes `ClassA` and `ClassB`, respectively, then you could access `ClassB` from `fileA.py` like this:

```
import fileB

instanceB = fileB.ClassB()
```